# How to export group history using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Somewhere I found a post in which I saw that telegram group history can be exported using following command.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        print( message.media)
```

I get some information print to screen. But I need need value of `messagemediaphoto`  caption name etc. How to get inner values.